# Strange error when installing extension over Magento Connect

Tags: error, extensions, magento-connect

I experienced an identical issue twice now on two separate installs on two separate environments. The first was on a client's production environment while I was trying to install an extension using Magento Connect. When I plugged in the extension key in step 2, I was presented with this:

```
error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

I shook it off and just installed the extension over FTP and continued about my day thinking something might be wrong with Magento Connect.

I then experienced the same issue with a clean install of 1.9.1.0 on a testing server I setup. Unable to proceed with extension install due to the same error.

Regarding SSL: The client's site has a fully verified SSL certificate. My testing server certificate was self-signed.

At this point I'm really just curious as to what causes it as I am able to proceed with FTP/SSH installs of my extension.

Additional Notes: Both instances were using Magento CE 1.9.1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Fix Magento Error:14077410:SSL Routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 Alert Handshake Failure!](https://www.dwdonline.com/blog/fix-magento-error14077410ssl-routinesssl23_get_server_hellosslv3-alert-handshake-failure.html)

> You can also just manually editing
>   downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client/Curl.php
>
> After: $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
>
> add: $this->curlOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you! Why does it affect some servers and not others? Any idea?

Comment: All servers should be disabling sslv3 support due to the POODLE exploit back in October 2014.